# What is the term for removing weeds from bodies of water?

Tags: weed-control, weeds, terminology, water

A control technique before planting aquatic plants in water bodies is to remove existing water weeds. I've heard of this being called "uprooting" or "cutting" the weeds. What's the proper term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term I've generally heard used for this is "harvesting".

Technically, uprooting or cutting the weeds only really covers disconnecting the plant from the ground. Harvesting, however, also includes the collection and removal of said weeds, which is necessary for actual control of the issue.

[This](http://pubs.ext.vt.edu/420/420-251/420-251.html) publication by Virginia Tech mentions it specifically as Harvesting and some others talk about the physical removal of weeds (vs. chemical) when discussing mechanical harvesting methods, e.g. [this paper by Clemson](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/plants/other/landscaping/hgic1714.html)